# Fitting in gnuplot with three variables

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to fit some data using gnuplot.

Here is the data (variables h, k,l and I):

```
#h  k   l   I

2   1   1   7807
2   2   0   9664
3   2   1   6042
4   0   0   1394
3   3   2   1358
4   2   0   4896

### Function
I(h,k,l) = M * (F * ( (sin(A*pi*sqrt(h*h+k*k+l*l)*L))/(A*2*pi*sqrt(h*h+k*k+l*l)) ))^2

### Initial values
M=1
F=0.5
A=1
L=1

### Fitting 
fit I(h,k,l) "cavendish.data" using 1:2:3 via M, F, A, L
```

I want to determine the constants M,F,A and L from this fitting.

When I run this code I get message **undefined variable: h**

How can I could determine the variables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have three variables, but one: the quadratic mean of h,k,l, that you should move from I(h,k,l) to the `using` statement. And your initial values seem to be way off, the fit converges far away on something that does not look very cystallographic. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a recent version of gnuplot (>= 5.0), which supports fit commands with more than two variables (see [release notes](http://www.gnuplot.info/ReleaseNotes_5_0.html)). Also note, that the power operator in gnuplot is `**` and not `^`.

You're example has to be changed slightly to work:

```
### Function
I(h,k,l) = M * (F * ((sin(A*pi*sqrt(h*h+k*k+l*l)*L))/(A*2*pi*sqrt(h*h+k*k+l*l)) ))**2

### Initial values
M=1.0
F=0.5
A=1.0
L=1.0

### Fitting
set dummy h, k, l
fit I(h,k,l) "cavendish.data" using 1:2:3:4 via M, F, A, L
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. Although I define dummy variables, I get error like this - (set dummy h, k, l;  "./script-curveFitting.sh", line 108: ';' expected).

Comment: additional info: The values for # h, k, l and I given at the beginning of my post is the data set I use for this code. The file "cavendish.data" contains these values.

Comment: I get the error you desribed only when using old gnuplot versions. Which version do you use?

Comment: sorry for late reply . . I use Version 4.6 patchlevel 4 .

Comment: As already explained above you need at least version 5.0 to do fitting with more than 2 variables.